# "Error: You may not call store.getState() while the reducer is executing."

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I just upgraded my fully functional react-native app to Redux v4, but now I am getting the following error:

> Error: Error: Error: Error: You may not call store.getState() while the reducer is executing. The reducer has already received the state as an argument. Pass it down from the top reducer instead of reading it from the store.

I suspect the problem is that I have numerous components inside others, each with their own `connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Component)` and I suppose this is not the correct way to implement it, though I am not sure the proper way to go about it.

Any direction is greatly appreciated!

Stack Trace:

```
    This error is located at:
    in Connect(SideBarApp) (at SceneView.js:9)
    in SceneView (at createTabNavigator.js:10)
    in RCTView (at View.js:43)
    in RCTView (at View.js:43)
    in ResourceSavingScene (at createBottomTabNavigator.js:86)
    in RCTView (at View.js:43)
    in RCTView (at View.js:43)
    in TabNavigationView (at createTabNavigator.js:127)
    in NavigationView (at createNavigator.js:59)
    in Navigator (at createNavigationContainer.js:376)
    in NavigationContainer (at SceneView.js:9)
    in SceneView (at SwitchView.js:12)
    in SwitchView (at createNavigator.js:59)
    in Navigator (at createNavigationContainer.js:376)
    in NavigationContainer (at AppNavigator.js:36)
    in App (created by Connect(App))
    in Connect(App) (at index.ios.js:23)
    in Provider (at index.ios.js:22)
    in TheNewsApp (at renderApplication.js:32)
    in RCTView (at View.js:43)
    in RCTView (at View.js:43)
    in AppContainer (at renderApplication.js:31)

This error is located at:
    in NavigationContainer (at SceneView.js:9)
    in SceneView (at SwitchView.js:12)
    in SwitchView (at createNavigator.js:59)
    in Navigator (at createNavigationContainer.js:376)
    in NavigationContainer (at AppNavigator.js:36)
    in App (created by Connect(App))
    in Connect(App) (at index.ios.js:23)
    in Provider (at index.ios.js:22)
    in TheNewsApp (at renderApplication.js:32)
    in RCTView (at View.js:43)
    in RCTView (at View.js:43)
    in AppContainer (at renderApplication.js:31)

This error is located at:
    in NavigationContainer (at AppNavigator.js:36)
    in App (created by Connect(App))
    in Connect(App) (at index.ios.js:23)
    in Provider (at index.ios.js:22)
    in TheNewsApp (at renderApplication.js:32)
    in RCTView (at View.js:43)
    in RCTView (at View.js:43)
    in AppContainer (at renderApplication.js:31)
getState@http://localhost:8081/index.ios.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false:79579:24
runComponentSelector@http://localhost:8081/index.ios.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false:78896:56
initSelector@http://localhost:8081/index.ios.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false:79019:28
Connect(SideBarApp)@http://localhost:8081/index.ios.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false:78969:29
constructClassInstance@http://localhost:8081/index.ios.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false:20826:32
updateClassComponent@http://localhost:8081/index.ios.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false:22393:35
performUnitOfWork@http://localhost:8081/index.ios.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false:24922:27
workLoop@http://localhost:8081/index.ios.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false:24955:47
renderRoot@http://localhost:8081/index.ios.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false:24988:21
performWorkOnRoot@http://localhost:8081/index.ios.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false:25549:23
performWork@http://localhost:8081/index.ios.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false:25481:30
performSyncWork@http://localhost:8081/index.ios.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false:25456:20
requestWork@http://localhost:8081/index.ios.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false:25362:26
scheduleWork@http://localhost:8081/index.ios.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false:25224:28
enqueueSetState@http://localhost:8081/index.ios.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false:20681:23
setState@http://localhost:8081/index.ios.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false:2380:37
dispatch@http://localhost:8081/index.ios.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false:80901:27
navigate@http://localhost:8081/index.ios.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false:80517:24
nav@http://localhost:8081/index.ios.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false:80470:44
combination@http://localhost:8081/index.ios.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false:79810:38
dispatch@http://localhost:8081/index.ios.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false:79628:38
setLoginStatus@http://localhost:8081/index.ios.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false:112247:19
http://localhost:8081/index.ios.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false:112199:44
tryCallOne@http://localhost:8081/index.ios.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false:8818:16
http://localhost:8081/index.ios.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false:8919:27
_callTimer@http://localhost:8081/index.ios.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false:8162:17
_callImmediatesPass@http://localhost:8081/index.ios.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false:8198:19
callImmediates@http://localhost:8081/index.ios.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false:8417:33
__callImmediates@http://localhost:8081/index.ios.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false:7741:32
http://localhost:8081/index.ios.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false:7580:34
__guard@http://localhost:8081/index.ios.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false:7721:15
flushedQueue@http://localhost:8081/index.ios.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false:7579:21
flushedQueue@[native code]
invokeCallbackAndReturnFlushedQueue@[native code]
```

Comment: Can you add a stack trace? This would help us give a more accurate answer.

Comment: Would you please share a snippet of the code where you actually call `store.getState()`?

Comment: I don't call store.getState()

Comment: It would be useful we could see what is going on at SceneView.js:9 and createTabNavigator.js:10

Comment: both of those are not my code. I'm not sure what SceneView comes from, but createTabNavigator is from react-navigation https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation

Answer (score 197):

### It's an issue with the **new v2.16.0 release** of **redux-devtools-extension**.

Here's a couple of **workaround** while we wait for the fix...

1. **Revert back** to the working version v2.15.5 (**For Chrome**)

   - Download https://github.com/zalmoxisus/redux-devtools-extension/releases/download/2.15.5/extension.zip
   - Extract the zip
   - Type `chrome://extensions` into the url and toggle on `developer mode` on the `top right` of the page.
   - The button `Load Unpacked` will appear. After clicking the button, select the extracted folder.
2. Or just simply **disable** your **redux-devtool extension** for now.

   - either on the browser level or through your code(where you create the redux store)

---

**FYI**: this does not solve the OP's question but does solve the issue where developers are receiving the below error message starting 11/27/18.

`Error: You may not call store.getState() while the reducer is executing. The reducer has already received the state as an argument. Pass it down from the top reducer instead of reading it from the store.`

---

### **UPDATE**

**v2.16.2** has been [released](https://github.com/zalmoxisus/redux-devtools-extension/issues/589#issuecomment-442413288)

For those who had previously disabled the extension, just re-enable it and Update your redux dev tools from 2.16.0 to 2.16.2 [Update Redux Dev tools](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/lmhkpmbekcpmknklioeibfkpmmfibljd)

Comment: Nice workaround for this problem which literally just popped up a hours ago for everyone using *redux-devtools-extension*, but doesn't really address OP's question which was asked way before this bugged v2.16.0 release...just saying

Comment: @bitstrider Of course it doesn't addresses the OP's question. But it sure seem like it's helping a lot of people out with the current situation. For those who are wondering about the status of this issue, here's the [github issue](https://github.com/zalmoxisus/redux-devtools-extension/issues/588) that was posted for it.

Comment: saved me alot of headache this early morning

Comment: spent almost an hour to find this issue. Reverted to v2.15.5. Things working fine now.

Comment: Version 2.16.1 of redux-devtools-extension, which fixes this issue, has been released

Comment: Great shout. Started seeing this error all of a sudden for no apparent reason. Disabling redux dev tools fixes it.

Comment: Confirming what Patrick mentions, that v2.16.1 fixes this issue. Just close and restart Chrome - the extension should auto update itself. All is well again in Redux Dev Tools world :)

Comment: I have dissabled the redux-devtool extension, but still the error. What should i do now?

Answer (score 24):

In my case, I have to remove [composeWithDevTools](https://github.com/zalmoxisus/redux-devtools-extension) - a plugin for chrome

```
import { createStore, combineReducers, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import { composeWithDevTools } from 'redux-devtools-extension';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';

// const enhancer = composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(thunk))
const enhancer = applyMiddleware(thunk)

const store = createStore(reducers, enhancer);
```

Comment: Thanks. This works for me. Disabling Redux Chrome Extension works as well. This only happens since today. wonder why...

Comment: Same here @JacobGoh , facing the same problem, never faced it before. Chrome webstore says the extension was updated on 27th November, maybe they broke something.

Comment: @JacobGoh https://github.com/zalmoxisus/redux-devtools-extension/issues/588

Comment: @ImanMahmoudinasab - I am using Chrome version 55.x (though latest version is 70.x), still faced the same issue. After uninstalling Redux DevTools (v 2.16.0), my app is working fine as suggested by Viet Le.

Answer (score 11):

In my project. This issue just popup from nowhere one day.

My solution: **Disable the Chrome extension - Redux Devtools.**
Then everything is back to normal.

So with this kind of error, you should test in several browser to find the problem.

Answer (score 7):

### tl;dr

Make sure you don't have any code that causes side effects in your reducers!

### Pure reducers

Redux reducers need to be pure. This means they shouldn't have side effects. Side effects should go to thunks or sagas. In my case a reducer looked like this:

```
case REDIRECT_ON_EVENT: {
  history.push('/some-route'); // side effect: redirection
  return {
    ...state,
    path: action.payload.path,
  };
}
```

The `history.push('/some-route');` part messed up state management. Removing it from the reducer and placing it to a saga that gets called on the same action type fixed the issue:

```
function redirectToSomeRoute() {
  history.push('/some-route');
}

takeEvery(REDIRECT_ON_EVENT, redirectToSomeRoute),
```

Answer (score 5):

Disabling chrome extension or removing `composeWithDevTool` from your code will work as a quick fix. But we all know that we need the extension in order to track our application state and manage it properly. So I created an issue today please support hopefully, someone from the redux team will get back to us.

Or if you are looking for a temporary workaround(for chrome), you can download https://github.com/zalmoxisus/redux-devtools-extension/releases/download/2.15.5/extension.zip and then extract it to some folder.

Type chrome://extensions and turn on developer mode from top left and then click on Load Unpacked and select the extracted folder for use.

Issue: https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-devtools/issues/413

Answer (score 5):

**Solution That work for me**

Disable the Chrome extension of **Redux Dev tools**. or remove **logger** from your code.

**update**: Update your redux dev tools from 2.16.0 to 2.16.1
[Update Redux Dev tools](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/lmhkpmbekcpmknklioeibfkpmmfibljd).

Answer (score 3):

In my case the issue was not related to dev extension. I've encountered this error while working with deep-linking - was updating route query inside reducer. Wrapping logic related to manipulating url inside settimeout fixed the error.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same error with a PWA build with polymer 3.
The store.js also tried to use the redux dev tools which I had to deactivate:

```js
...
// Sets up a Chrome extension for time travel debugging.
// See https://github.com/zalmoxisus/redux-devtools-extension for more information.
//const devCompose = window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ || compose;
const devCompose =  compose;

// Initializes the Redux store with a lazyReducerEnhancer (so that you can
// lazily add reducers after the store has been created) and redux-thunk (so
// that you can dispatch async actions). See the "Redux and state management"
// section of the wiki for more details:
// https://github.com/Polymer/pwa-starter-kit/wiki/4.-Redux-and-state-management
export const store = createStore(
  state => state,
  devCompose(
    lazyReducerEnhancer(combineReducers),
    applyMiddleware(thunk))
);
...
```

Answer (score 2):

This is what I did: Just commented the line for Chrome Redux Devtools Extension from my store.js file.

```
....

 const store = createStore(
  rootReducer,
  initialState,
  compose(
    applyMiddleware(...middleware)
   ///This line--> window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ && window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__() 
  )
);

....
```

And the issue is just begun an hour ago. As we all know the extension is very handy during development, so let us wait for the real fix from the authorities.

Answer (score 2):

Should be fixed now. Update your redux dev tools from 2.16.0 to 2.16.1

https://github.com/zalmoxisus/redux-devtools-extension/issues/588#issuecomment-442396540

Comment: It still happens for me on 2.17.0

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem on Chrome.  Downgrading my version of redux from 4.0.2 to 3.7.2 fixed it for me.

`npm uninstall redux`

`npm install redux@3.7.2`

Answer (score 1):

> **Note**: I am using Saga

In my case I had added a navigation code inside a reducer.

```js
    sendOTPSuccess: (state, action) => {
      state.wip = false;

      RootNavigation.navigate('LoginOTPScreen');
    },
```

In the beginning it was working but when I used/accessed state inside the called new Screen

```js
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import * as sessionActions from "../../models/session";

const LoginOTP: () => Node = (props) => {
  const session = useSelector(sessionActions.selectSession);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  ...
```

the error popped up.

```
“Error: You may not call store.getState() while the reducer is executing.”
```

### Cause

Reducer is supposed to be a pure function. It should accept a payload and modify state and nothing else. Something else is considered as a side-effect.

I my case I loaded a new component which also consumes `state` data and the state modification is not yet completed. This is causing the issue.

### Solution

I simply moved the navigation to respective `saga`

```js
// worker Saga:
function* sendOTPSaga({ payload }) {
  const { phoneNumber } = payload;
  try {
    const response = yield call(Api.sendOtp, { phoneNumber });
    if (response.status == 200) {
      yield put(sessionActions.sendOTPSuccess(response.data));
      RootNavigation.navigate('LoginOTPScreen'); // <---- Here
    ...
```