# You may not call store.getState()

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome, redux, google-chrome-devtools

As the title says. I added

```
// Create Store
const store = createStoreWithFirebase(
rootReducer,
initialState,
composeWithDevTools(reactReduxFirebase(firebase))
);
```

This works fine in a browser without the redux extension installed. IE safari, chrome incognito. The instant I try to run the site with the extension installed I get.

> Error: You may not call store.getState() while the reducer is executing. The reducer has already received the state as an argument. Pass it down from the top reducer instead of reading it from the store.

[image: Error of image]

If I change

```
composeWithDevTools()
```

To

```
compose()
```

The application works fine.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Error: Error: Error: Error: You may not call store.getState() while the reducer is executing." ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51503198/error-error-error-error-you-may-not-call-store-getstate-while-the-reducer)

Comment: Please show the code and/or state the errors. Please don't use links to images. The text is missing from the question. The text on the picture is too small for some people to read. The text on the image cannot be indexed by search engines for future visitors.

Comment: It's a bug with redux dev tools, see the link that Abdul posted

Answer (score 1):

As user **Victor Le** commented at this other post:
 ["Error: Error: Error: Error: You may not call store.getState() while the reducer is executing." 🤔](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51503198/error-error-error-error-you-may-not-call-store-getstate-while-the-reducer#)

It's an issue with the new v2.16.0 release of redux-devtools-extension.
Just disable it, don't use it or downgrade to v2.15.

The post above is really useful.

Best!

Comment: Its better to flag it duplicate instead of posting link of question.