# Error: Redux dispatch can not be called while the reducer is executing?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, dispatch

It says that:

**Error**: You may not call store.getState() while the reducer is executing. The reducer has already received the state as an argument. Pass it down from the top reducer instead of reading it from the store.

I solve the issue but I still want to know **How to pass it down from the top reducer instead of reading it from the store**?

Comment: Can u share the code with this

Comment: Can you include your Reducer code?

Comment: It's a bug with the current version of redux dev tools. Deactivate them or downgrade until a fix is available

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Error: Error: Error: Error: You may not call store.getState() while the reducer is executing." ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51503198/error-error-error-error-you-may-not-call-store-getstate-while-the-reducer)

Answer (score 0):

As user **Victor Le** commented at this other post: "Error: Error: Error: Error: You may not call store.getState() while the reducer is executing."

It's an issue with the new v2.16.0 release of redux-devtools-extension. Just disable it, don't use it or downgrade to v2.15.

The post above is really useful.

Best!