# React: Uncaught error: Getting react-redux issue

Tags: reactjs, redux

Since today morning I am getting following error for mine reactjs web app.

Uncaught Error: You may not call `store.getState()` while the reducer is executing. The reducer has already received the state as an argument. Pass it down from the top reducer instead of reading it from the store.

It was working till yesterday but not sure whats happening? Help will be appreciable!

Comment: May be you can found any help here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51503198/error-error-error-error-you-may-not-call-store-getstate-while-the-reducer

Comment: tldr; Revert back to the working version(v2.15.5)

Comment: Thanks JenuJ. it worked! I disabled chrome extension! Hopefully extension team will fix those bugs in latest versions!

Answer (score 0):

**Quick Solution**

Disable the Chrome extension of **Redux Dev tools** or remove **logger** from your code.